# Visual bug in Dock after macOS Mojave installation

Tags: macos, dock, mojave

After installing the macOS Mojave update, I get a strange visual bug in the Dock from time to time. It disappears when I click on something in the Dock or if I try to make a screenshot (that's why I had to capture the screenshot using camera instead of screenshots).

1. There is a horizontal line between the Mail and Calendar app icons and one in the middle of the Notes icon:

[image]

2. There is a horizontal line in the middle of the ForkLift icon:

[image]

**Note**: When installing the macOS Mojave update, my Mac got stuck on the analytics screen (like described here: [Mojave install froze on "analytics", successful force reboot- but did it miss anything?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337467/mojave-install-froze-on-analytics-successful-force-reboot-but-did-it-miss-an)) and I had to restart it manually. Maybe that has corrupted my installation?

I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14 on a 2014 MacBook Pro.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

**Edit:**

It looks like that this bug isn't linked to specific icons on the Dock. It appears randomly and disappears when I click on the dock. It looks a bit like it only appears next to active apps most of the time. It's still present after several restarts of my MacBook.

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I was able to reproduce this bug. I appears every time I minimize a window. You can see it here:
[image]
You have to look closely to the Postman icon (the 6th from the left), the Mail icon (10th) and the Notes icon (12th) after I minimize Chrome. You can see the bright square until I click on the Chrome icon again.

**Edit 3:**

I updated my Mac to 10.14.2 and the bug still appears.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain  the 'visual bug' that you see?  I'm not able to see anything wrong in the images, maybe I'm just missing it.

Comment: I did so. I know that it's really hard to see on these images.

Comment: Have you tried just reinstalling the system again, and letting it complete fully. That may not help but its such an easy first step its well worth a shot.

Comment: Would that override my OS settings and app installations? I hesitate to do this because I need this MacBook for work.

Comment: There is a more recent update 10.14.3. Maybe updating to that will help?

Comment: Also, can you disable this option under Dock Preferences? System Preferences > Dock > Minimize windows into application icon. See if this changes that issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late response @chrisdahfuh. The latest update didn't resolved the issue. After `Minimize windows into application icon` the bug seems to be gone but that's not really a solution I'm comfortable with.

Comment: Having same issue on latest iMac with Vega48

Comment: Bug is still here on Catalina 10.15.3 :(

Answer (score 2):

I have this exact problem while connected on an external monitor using a Macbook Pro 2017. The problem is the window animation, I experience this problem using the **Scale Effect** animation but it disappears as soon as I am using the **Genie Effect**. That's an acceptable workaround, still I wonder how this is not fixed on Apple's side.